# How to access the selection object in _execute javascript method to add a button to ribbon toolbar? And how to add images to the button?

Tags: javascript, css, tridion

I am unable to access the selection object in `_execute` method of JavaScript. If I try to access it giving error as "unsupported function/object".

Another problem is that the icon images for my ribbon tool bar button are not getting reflected.

Comment: Since you get very concrete error messages, would you mind sharing the code that causes that error message with us? Just copy/paste it in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How have you defined you execute function? Here's one where the selection is accessible:

```
Sample.Commands.Example.prototype._execute=function Example$_execute(selection) 
{
    if (selection.getCount() == 1) {
        var uriSelection = selection.getItem(0);
        // Do something else
    }
};
```

For ribbon toolbar button icons, try something like the following in your CSS:

```
.tridion .ribbontoolbar .button.Example.text { 
    background-image:
        url(/WebUI/Editors/Sample/Themes/images/icons/example-icon32x32.png);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response... I used the same syntax but the problem exactly is inside that function Visual Basic is not listing any properties for selection object. If we use getItem() method it is giving "Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 519 Char: 411 Code: 0 URI: http://hydhtc131406d:1000/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Component/Component_v6.1.0.55920.2_.aspx?mode=js".
Fast reply would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Quick question. Are you asking how to get IntelliSense on the JavaScript objects?

Comment: As Frank has suggested, perhaps you can update your original question with the code that doesn't work? It'd be a lot easier to troubleshoot it than without the code ;)